# How do you declare a Char literal in Visual Basic .NET?

Tags: vb.net, literals

With `Option Strict On`:

```
Dim theLetterA As Char = "A"
```

returns an error about converting the string `"A"` to a `Char`.

What is the syntax to enter a `Char` literal?

Answer (score 182, accepted):

A character literal is entered using a single character string suffixed with a `C`.

```
Dim theLetterA As Char = "A"C
```

Comment: That really sucks, breaks every convention! Thanks for your help

Comment: Actually literal suffixing to indicate type is as old as C and Basic albeit not for string related types, and I too did feel it was a bit dubious the first time I saw it.

Comment: I needed to use """"C to trim quotes from a string. How ugly.

Comment: This made me die a little inside.

Comment: Lowercase 'c' works too. Slightly less ugly. This isn't much different from declaring for example Python strings as unicode literals, is it?

Comment: VS 2017 (15.5.6) changed the capital C I added to lowercase - I'm assuming this is preferred by Microsoft.

Comment: I'm still looking for a better option... VB will die without it.

Comment: How is this any different or more ugly then float support in C#? const float pi = 3.14159F

Answer (score 9):

I would use CChar.  E.g.:

```
 Dim theLetterA As Char = CChar("A")
```

Check the MSDN website https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2dy91zy.aspx for details on CChar.

Comment: Deserves more upvotes.  A char ctor makes more sense than a string decorator like I've never seen before.

Comment: @RJB: You may like the syntax better, but the fact is that this is *not* a character literal.  It's a statement that performs a runtime conversion from a string to a character. Not the same at all.

Comment: I agree.  this is old VB code and requires the visualbasic reference.  The right way is to use the convert class.     Convert.ToChar("A")

Comment: @sstan I don't have any official statement, but it's very probable the compiler threats that sequence as character literal ("A"c) on compile time.

Comment: @Kevbo - that's still a runtime action, instead of a character literal. Probably inefficient. More importantly, much more verbose. How is `Convert.ToChar("A")` a readability improvement over `"A"c`?

Answer (score 2):

In the case of trying to get a double quote as a character literal, you'll need to use the extra quirky VB format:

```
Dim theQuote As Char = """"C
```

Or

```
Dim theQuote As Char = CChar("""")
```

Comment: Depends on your definition of readable I suppose. I usually avoid "magic numbers" myself, and although the VB expression is quirky AF, you'd never have to pull up an ASCII table to check it was right.

Comment: I see. I don't think the ASCII code is "magic" when talking about a CHAR because that is the actual number held by the CHAR. A char is a number. If you were to inspect the memory for `theQuote` you would see `34`.