# Find average of all digits in string

Tags: vb.net, string, char, string-function

I'm trying to find the count of the digits, the lowest digit, the highest digit, and the average of all the digits in a string.

This is what I was able to come up with so far

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Dim minimumInt As Integer
        Dim maximumInt As Integer
        Dim averageInt As Single
        For Each c As Char In TextBox1.Text
            If Char.IsDigit(c) Then
                i = i + 1
                If (Asc(c) < minimumInt) Then
                    minimumInt = Asc(c)
                ElseIf (Asc(c) > maximumInt) Then
                    maximumInt = Asc(c)
                End If
                averageInt = averageInt + Asc(c)
                averageInt = averageInt / i
            End If
        Next
        MessageBox.Show("Total Digits: " & i & ControlChars.CrLf & "Average Number: " & averageInt & ControlChars.CrLf & "Minimum Number: " & minimumInt & ControlChars.CrLf & "Maximum Number: " & maximumInt)
    End Sub
End Class
```

I believe the issue is involving converting Chars to Integers.

**For example, when TextBox1 contains "X13210AS", I get this**
[http://i.imgur.com/5aaOWC0.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoogA.png)

When I should be getting an average of 1.4 and highest digit 3.

Any ideas on how to fix this while still using the majority of my code?

Comment: Ah, I wrote it in the question already. `TextBox1` contains '"X13210AS"'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is with the [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) conversion. "0" char is having value of 48.

The second issue is with your averaging, which should be done after you get all numbers instead of each loop. **And beware of division by 0!**

To get it right, you have to do this:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Dim minimumInt As Integer
        Dim maximumInt As Integer
        Dim averageInt As Single
        Dim intVal As Integer 'only use this
        For Each c As Char In TextBox1.Text
            If Char.IsDigit(c) Then
                i = i + 1
                intVal = Asc(c) - 48 'count this once, note -48 here is to convert ASCII rep to integer value
                If (intVal < minimumInt) Then
                    minimumInt = intVal
                ElseIf (intVal > maximumInt) Then
                    maximumInt = intVal
                End If
                averageInt += intVal
            End If
        Next
        If i <> 0 Then 'beware of 0
            averageInt = averageInt / i `put this outside
        End If
        MessageBox.Show("Total Digits: " & i & ControlChars.CrLf & "Average Number: " & averageInt & ControlChars.CrLf & "Minimum Number: " & minimumInt & ControlChars.CrLf & "Maximum Number: " & maximumInt)
    End Sub
End Class
```

And you will get this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`Asc(c)` returns the ASCII value of the digit character, so e.g. '0' has an ASCII value of 48.

Assuming your goal is to ignore non-digits and average the rest, you will almost get you the correct average of you adjust for 0 = 48, 1 = 49, etc. You need to do this step

```
averageInt = averageInt / i
```

after the loop is done.

Your minimum value is 0 because minimumInt starts as 0. Start with minimumInt  = Asc('9') or a similar high value.

Comment: So from my understanding, I would have to put `Asc(c - 48)`? but that doesn't work and when I put the - 48 outside of the conversion, I get more jibberish

Comment: No, `Asc(c)  - 48`, or perhaps to be more clear `Asc(c) - Asc('0')`. Also note I edited my question just now, pointing out that the final step of the average calculation needs to happen outside of the loop.

Comment: One lasttt question, sorry! But why do you put the numbers inside single quotes? When I do, I end up getting comments, are single quotes the same as Double quotes in vb.net?

Comment: @IdkHowToCodeAtAll Single quote is for character writing in VB.Net, thus 0 is integer (having value of 0) but "0'" is character (having value of 48)

Comment: I'm a C# guy... character constants are in single quotes. I guess it would be "0"C in VB.Net http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3374842/how-do-you-declare-a-char-literal-in-visual-basic-net

Comment: You guys are the best.

Answer (score 0):

Using [**regex**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312(v=vs.110).aspx) and [**List**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
```

you can do it in a simple way

```
TextBox1.Text = "X13210AS"
Dim lstnums As List(Of Integer) = Regex.Replace(TextBox1.Text, "[^\d]", ""). _
                                  Select(Function(x) Val(x)).ToList
Dim maxnum, minnum As Integer
Dim avg As Double

maxnum = lstnums.Max()
minnum = lstnums.Min()
avg = lstnums.Average
MessageBox.Show("Total Digits: " & Val(lstnums.Count) & ControlChars.CrLf & "Average Number: " & avg & ControlChars.CrLf & "Minimum Number: " & minnum & ControlChars.CrLf & "Maximum Number: " & maxnum)
```

---

`[^\d]` is the pattern to match integer in `Textbox1`