# How to unmask a password textbox?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I would like to toggle the password visibility of a textbox with a checkbox element. So whenever the state changes I would like to display the password with password characters or plain text.

Using C# I can simply assign a password character for asterisks via

```
textBox.PasswordChar = '*';
```

and for plain text

```
textBox.PasswordChar = '\0';
```

With VB I currently have this sample code

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
    If CheckBox1.Checked Then
        TextBox1.PasswordChar = '\0'
        CheckBox1.Text = "Hide password"
    Else
        TextBox1.PasswordChar = '*'
        CheckBox1.Text = "Show password"
    End If
End Sub
```

and found some information here

[How do you declare a Char literal in Visual Basic .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3374842/how-do-you-declare-a-char-literal-in-visual-basic-net)

I know that `'` is considered as a comment so I have to use double-quotes. I can update `'*'` to `"*"C` but what's the equivalent for `'\0'`?

What is the correct way to unmask the textbox password?

Comment: You can use `Nothing` or better use the `UseSystemPasswordChar` property instead.

Comment: You can set `TextBox1.PasswordChar = Char.MinValue`. If you want to set the default char, use `TextBox1.PasswordChar = ChrW(&H25CF)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the [`Nothing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/nothing) keyword which will set the default value for the expected type (`Char` in this case):

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
    TextBox1.PasswordChar = If(CheckBox1.Checked, Nothing, "*"c)
End Sub
```

A better way would be to use the [`UseSystemPasswordChar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox.usesystempasswordchar) property instead of `PasswordChar`. This makes the password mask look "more standard". That's, of course, unless you want to use a custom char. Here's an example:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
    TextBox1.UseSystemPasswordChar = Not CheckBox1.Checked
End Sub
```

Comment: Note that setting `UseSystemPasswordChar` at run-time, the TextBox needs to recreate the Handle. It may have consequences.

Comment: @Jimi Thanks for the tip :) I actually didn't know that. And it's not even mentioned in the docs. What kind of consequences do you think this might have though?

Comment: See code and notes (comments) in [RecreateHandleCore()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,10947) and the reason why I posted that comment (on the question): [PasswordProtect](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TextBox.cs,302)